# I need help trying to make a functional Zenity list

Tags: gnome-terminal, grep, zenity

Here is what I have so far

```
#!/bin/bash

zenity --list --title "Packages" --list  --text "select packages you want to install" --checklist --column "id"  --column "Name" 1 "PASSOWRD" 2 "BOOKS" 3 "Firefox" 4 "GIMP"
```

I want to make PASSWORD run a script once it has been selected and 'OK' is pressed  here is the script I want it to run in terminal

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/meg/meg_rw/userpath

grep -oP '(?<=Password: ).*' pw.dat

$SHELL
```

Comment: What exactly is the question/problem?

Comment: I want to know how I can make it so when I run the script the list comes up and when the password column is checked it runs its associated command in terminal

Answer (score 0):

Zenity returns the selected column names as list separated by the "separator" character.

This is the answer for your question:

```
#!/bin/bash

zret="$( zenity --list --title "Packages" --list \
    --text "select packages you want to install" \
    --checklist --column "id"  --column "Name" 1 \
    "PASSWORD" 2 "BOOKS" 3 "Firefox" 4 "GIMP" )

if grep -qw PASSWORD <<<"${zret}"; then
    run_your_command
fi
```

I hope it is okay that I removed the typo in "PASSOWRD".

From your comment I extend it (Next time, put it in the question!).

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS='|' read -r -a zret <<<"$( zenity --list \
    --title "Packages" --list \
    --text "select packages you want to install" --checklist \
    --column "id" --column "Name" \
    1 "PASSWORD" 2 "BOOKS" 3 "Firefox" 4 "GIMP" )"

for z in "${zret[@]}"; do
    case "${z}" in
    PASSWORD)
        task_password
        ;;
    BOOKS)
        task_books
        ;;
    Firefox)
        task_firefox
        ;;
    GIMP)
        task_gimp
        ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate it!

Comment: Can I just copy that for the rest of the Column names Like if I wanted to add a command for " BOOKS" I would just do the same right?